# Check a radio button if ngModel is not equal to a fixed value

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button

I have two radio buttons. I wanna check the first radio button if ngModel has value of X, and if ngModel has any value other than X then the second radio button must be checked. It means the second radio button doesn't have a fixed value. It can be anything except X. 
I can't achieve this with following code:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="x">
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="">
```

So in this case if color.name is equal to x then first radio is checked but if color.name is not equal to x then none of the radio are checked by default. 
How can I fix the second radio button's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-checked="color.name == 'x'" value="x">
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-checked="color.name != 'x'" value="">
```

Comment: In my code, `<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-checked="color.name == 'x'" value="x">
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-checked="color.name != 'x'" value="">` . While `color.name` changed, radio changed too.

Answer (score 0):

***I fixed this problem with conditional ngValue***.

In Angular, if ngModel and the value of a radio button are the same then that radio is checked. So with conditional ngValue we can get what we want:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="x">
<input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="color.name == 'x' ? '' : color.name">
```